# How can I assign Application User Model ID to my app?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

One of the requirements for my application MSI-package is to have Application User Model ID (AUMID). It looks like my app doesn't have it, so I need to tweak the project. Should that be done via InstallShield? Is there some tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you need to [assign it from your source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76465222/how-can-i-assign-application-user-model-id-to-my-app). But I have never done this so I may be understanding the docs incorrectly.

What are you trying to achieve in the end, why do you need the user model ID for?